# Почему может не запускаться mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Проверяю статус:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

[image: Все хорошо]

Далее запускаю `mongo`:

[image: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :]

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
```

Comment: а в конфиге что? Может она не слушает на этом адресе/порту?